# Cannot drop the database 'DB', because it does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2013, entity-framework-6

I am working a school project with three other group members.  We are using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013, and using Visual Studio Online as version control.  The project is worked with .Net MVC 5 EF6.  Our group is having troubles that we cannot figure out.

Here is the problem we are having.  Every time that one of use grabs the newest version control changes and attempts to run the project with or without debug we get an error in browser:

"Cannot drop the database 'DB', because it does not exist or you do not have permission."

We can get it to work if we add a migration and update database.  But this is causing us to have to migrate way to often and causing a lot of headaches.

We cannot figure out if we have a setting messed up or something else.  I am hoping that someone can help us resolve this issue so we can get back to working more efficiently.

Also site and DB are hosted on goDaddy.

Comment: I doubt it is something to do with version control.  How have you configured migrations?  It sounds like you are recreating the DB everytime the app starts up?  When you add a migration, what type of stuff does it add?

Comment: Nothing, the migrations are empty.

Comment: Yes - what about the configuration?

Comment: Are you using code-first model?

Comment: Yes code-first model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bet is that you have `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` set to `true`, otherwise your application wouldn't be trying to do anything with your database just because you pulled the latest version from TFS.

Also, automatic migrations don't try to drop your database, not unless your have `DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges` or `DropCreateDatabaseAlways` database initializers set up. Check your code. You probably have. [Here's an article](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c19999/Understanding-Database-Initializers-in-Entity-Framework-Code-First.htm). Please do not have these on production.

Also, your villain database initializer isn't being able to do it's job because the ASP.NET user on GoDaddy probably doesn't have permission to do so.

My advice: Disable `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled`. Do you migrations manually with `add-migration` and `update-database`. `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled` is not a good practice. It's even being discontinued from EF7. That should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which is worse: using GoDaddy as an ISP, or using VSS/TFS for version control :(

ANYWAY - Two suggestions:

1) Use local workspaces (and just checkin/checkout updates when you wish to synchronize):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx

2) See if VSO supports a macro or script to "kill all" connections before you sync versions:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b41a7376-d5cd-4339-92b3-158e88a96dff/how-can-i-kill-all-connections-of-users-to-my-sql-server-database-?forum=adodotnetentityframework